# Auto wrap in Kartik Gridview Datacolumn

Tags: php, gridview, yii2

I have a kartik's gridview widget in my Yii2 template page and it lists the data fetched from the database, however if the data is too long it shows a horizontal scroll at the bottom of the widget but I want it to auto wrap content of the column just to fit in the page. Here is my code

```
    <?= GridView::widget([
    'responsiveWrap' => false,
    'hover' => true,

    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'kartik\grid\SerialColumn'],
        'conf_key',
        ['attribute' => 'conf_value',
            'class' => 'kartik\grid\DataColumn',
            'noWrap' => false
        ],

        'class_name',
        ['class' => 'kartik\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ],
]); ?>
```

I want to wrap conf_value column for example how to do it?
here i put the screenshot how widget looks
[image: gridview no wrap column]

Note: noWrap doesn't work because the data have no whitespace!

Comment: see this link, it might help you, http://jsfiddle.net/Daniel_Hug/Sp5g6/ and http://jsfiddle.net/gryzzly/cbppl/

Comment: what exacyly you want to do with that, break to certain characters or, on hover show the data??

Comment: not break to certain characters, jut fit it in the column say it 50% of the table it is in.

Comment: use `word-wrap: break-word;` see demo here http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/pTH6Y/ and http://jsfiddle.net/Shreerang/ZQ9MY/light/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks gamitg for giving me a light so i have changed my code as

```
    <?= GridView::widget([
    'responsiveWrap' => false,
    'hover' => true,

    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'kartik\grid\SerialColumn'],
        'conf_key',
        ['attribute' => 'conf_value',
            'class' => 'kartik\grid\DataColumn',
            'noWrap' => false,
            //the line below has solved the issue
            'contentOptions' => 
            ['style'=>'max-width: 350px; overflow: auto; word-wrap: break-word;']
            ,
        ],
        'class_name',
        ['class' => 'kartik\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ],
]); ?>
```

but I can't give percentage to max-width like max-width: 50%; is there any opinion?

Comment: `max-width` is maximum value of width that means limit of content area so, you can give `pixel` or `emn`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `max-width` in css.

Like as,

```
td {
    max-width: 100px;
    overflow: auto; /* optional */
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

**Note:** Tested on your code snippet.

Comment: where to write this css i couldn't find the right td class within bootstrap.css (at least tried with no success)

Comment: I have use this css as internal css. but you can use class like as `.kv-grid-table > tbody > tr > td`.