# Kartik gridView text doesn't wrap in the cell

Tags: php, gridview, yii2

I am using kartik gridView to show data.
I am trying to provide width to the columns but my data overflow out of it's cell boundary and doesn't wrap. I am using following code :

```
$columns = [
    ['class'=>'kartik\grid\SerialColumn', 'width'=>'38px'],

    [
        'attribute'=>'bill_number', 
        'vAlign'=>'middle',
        'hAlign'=>'left',             
        'noWrap' => false,
        'headerOptions'=>['style'=>'max-width: 100px;'],
        'contentOptions'=>['style'=>'max-width: 100px;'],
        'format'=>['html'],
        'pageSummary'=>'Page Total'
    ],

    [
        'attribute'=>'bill_date', 
        'vAlign'=>'middle',
        'hAlign'=>'left', 

        'noWrap' => false,
        'headerOptions'=>['style'=>'max-width: 100px;'],
        'contentOptions'=>['style'=>'max-width: 100px;'],
    ],

    [
        'attribute'=>'party_name', 
        'vAlign'=>'middle',
        'hAlign'=>'left', 

        'noWrap' => false,
        'headerOptions'=>['style'=>'max-width: 100px;'],
        'contentOptions'=>['style'=>'max-width: 100px;'],
        'format'=>['html'],
    ],
    [
        'attribute'=>'assignment_name', 
        'vAlign'=>'middle',
        'hAlign'=>'left',            
        'noWrap' => false,
        'headerOptions'=>['style'=>'max-width: 100px;'],
        'contentOptions'=>['style'=>'max-width: 100px;'],
    ],

    [
        'attribute'=>'particulars', 
        'vAlign'=>'middle',
        'hAlign'=>'left',             
        'noWrap' => false,
        'headerOptions'=>['style'=>'max-width: 100px;'],
        'contentOptions'=>['style'=>'max-width: 100px;'],
        'format'=>['html'],
    ],     

    [
        'attribute'=>'0-60 days', 
        'label'=>'0-60 days',
        'vAlign'=>'middle',
        'hAlign'=>'right',
        'headerOptions'=>['style'=>'max-width: 100px;'],
        'contentOptions'=>['style'=>'max-width: 100px;'],
        'format'=>['decimal', 0],
        'pageSummary'=>true
    ],

    [
        'attribute'=>'60-90 days', 
        'label'=>'60-90 days', 
        'vAlign'=>'middle',
        'hAlign'=>'right',
        'headerOptions'=>['style'=>'max-width: 100px;'],
        'contentOptions'=>['style'=>'max-width: 100px;'],
        'format'=>['decimal', 0],
        'pageSummary'=>true
    ],

    [
        'attribute'=>'90-180 days',
        'label'=>'90-180 days', 
        'vAlign'=>'middle',
        'hAlign'=>'right',            
        'headerOptions'=>['style'=>'max-width: 100px;'],
        'contentOptions'=>['style'=>'max-width: 100px;'],
        'format'=>['decimal', 0],
        'pageSummary'=>true
    ],
    [
        'attribute'=>'>180 days', 
        'vAlign'=>'middle',
        'hAlign'=>'right',            
        'headerOptions'=>['style'=>'max-width: 100px;'],
        'contentOptions'=>['style'=>'max-width: 100px;'],
        'format'=>['decimal', 0],
        'pageSummary'=>true
    ],
    [
        'attribute'=>'total', 
        'vAlign'=>'middle',
        'hAlign'=>'right', 
        'headerOptions'=>['style'=>'max-width: 100px;'],
        'contentOptions'=>['style'=>'max-width: 100px;'],
        'format'=>['decimal', 0],
        'pageSummary'=>true
    ],    
];

echo GridView::widget([
    'columns'=>$columns,
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'floatHeader'=>true,
    'floatHeaderOptions'=>['top'=>'50px'],
    'floatOverflowContainer' => true,
    'responsiveWrap'=>false,
    'showPageSummary'=>true,
    'resizableColumns'=>true,
    'persistResize' => false,
    'panel' => [
        'type'=>GridView::TYPE_PRIMARY,

        'footer'=>false
    ],
    'containerOptions'=>['style'=>'overflow: auto'], 
]);
```

Kindly have a look on the screenshot[image: grid screenshot]

I want to wrap the text in the cell and adjust the row height according to the max cell height in that row.

Comment: Try using [width](http://demos.krajee.com/grid#data-column)

Comment: See this thread: [Auto wrap in kartik gridview column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33102752/auto-wrap-in-kartik-gridview-datacolumn)

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
[
    'attribute'=>'attribute', 
    'value'=>function($data){
      return wordwrap($data->attribute,15,'<br>');
    }
],
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this one

```
[
  'class' => 'kartik\grid\DataColumn',
  'attribute'=>'YOUR_ATTRIBUTE_NAME', 
  'headerOptions'=>['style'=>'max-width: 100px;'],
  'contentOptions'=>['style'=>'max-width: 100px;vertical-align:middle'],
  'format'=>'raw',
  'value' => function($model) {
          return "<p 'style'='max-width:150px; min-height:100px; 
           overflow: auto; word-wrap: break-word;'>". $model->YOUR_ATTRIBUTE_NAME."</p>";
  },
],
```

Comment: It didn't work. I am attaching a screenshot kindly view it. this gridview is nested inside another gridview. Will this information help

Answer (score -1):

HTML tag, do not attach in *value* slot, it have to add in **contentOptions** and style it ...